# Detected Problems with app native libraries in Nougat

Tags: android, android-ndk

I am working with android native libraries and while processing image I see a message saying

[image: this is the warning message]

This is the case when I use  `targetSdkVersion 22` if I do update `targetSdkVersion to 23` or above then it thows error

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: dlopen failed: /data/app/package-name-1/lib/arm/libjniopencv_core.so: has text relocations.
 at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:977)

at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:1530)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.loadLibrary(Loader.java:701)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:578)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:136)
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
                                                                          at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:400)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:553)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacpp.Loader.load(Loader.java:532)
                                                                          at com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core$CvSize.<clinit>(opencv_core.java:2560)
```

Please suggest.

Comment: Was libjniopencv_core.so built by you or did you download it from somewhere? Which NDK version was it built with? Do you still have the problem if you rebuild the library using the latest NDK version?

Comment: Odds are there's some hand written assembly in opencv that relies on text relocations, which aren't allowed in Android (it's a security issue, and it increases memory use). You should make sure you're on the latest version of opencv, and if you are, file a bug with opencv.

Comment: @user3930824 : Did u get the solution for this issue? Me too facing same problem. Please let me know

Comment: @Prakash you have to update javacpp from googlecode to bytedeco with newer vesrsion.